# how to dispatch requests in spring mvc base request parameters before it get's to dispatcher servlet?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm adding a feature to server which has to redirect a request base a specific request parameter to completely different URL out of project, otherwise it should proceed as normal to defined controller.
Is there any other way than defining an interceptor preHandle method? some sort of predefined class in spring that I can override and provide this dispatching thing for me?

Comment: Well, that's what an interceptor, or a filter is for. What's the problem with using one?

Comment: i'm looking if spring has any other predefined filters or classes for this specific purpose.

Comment: I doubt it. To be generic enough, it would have to be configured with the URL to redirect to, the condition for when to redirect, and in the end, you would have to write as much code as if you implemented the filter by yourself. It's just a few lines of code.